# How to initialize a non-POD member in Union

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, unions

In c++11, Union supports non-POD member. I want to initialize a non-POD member in the constructor.

On wikipedia c++11 [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Unrestricted_unions), it uses a placement 'new' to initialize a non-POD member.

```
#include <new> // Required for placement 'new'.

struct Point {
    Point() {}
    Point(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y) {}
    int x_, y_;
};

union U {
    int z;
    double w;
    Point p; // Illegal in C++03; legal in C++11.
    U() {new(&p) Point();} // Due to the Point member, a constructor definition is now required.
};
```

I am wondering is there any difference if I use ctor-initializer-list instead of placement 'new'?

```
U() : p() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No, no difference for you. Just use `U() : p() {}`.</strike>

> [ Note: In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new operators to change the active
>   member of a union. — end note ]
>
> [ Example: Consider an object u of a union type U having non-static data
>   members `m` of type `M` and `n` of type `N`. If `M` has a non-trivial destructor and `N` has a non-trivial constructor
>   (for instance, if they declare or inherit virtual functions), the active member of `u` can be safely switched from m to n using the destructor and placement new operator as follows:
>
> ```
> u.m.~M();
> new (&u.n) N;
> ```
>
> — end example ]

I.e. your first variant is correct.

---

The standard also says:

> At most one non-static data member of a union may have a brace-or-equal-initializer.

Personally, I would expect the following to be correct:

```
union U {
    int z;
    double w;
    Point p {1,2};
};

#include <iostream>
int main () {
    U u;
    std::cout << u.p.x_ << ":" << u.p.y_ << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect the output `1:2`, but with g++ 4.8.1 I get garbage values. When I try

```
union U {
    int z;
    double w;
    Point p = Point(1,2);
};
```

I get garbage values, too. I am not sure if this is a compiler bug.

**edit**: [brace-or-equal-Initializer in unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005241/brace-or-equal-initializer-in-unions)

Answer (score 1):

You are free to initialize at most one member of a union in the *ctor-initializer-list*. A union is a class, so the rules for member initializers in [class.base.init] (C++11 §12.6.2) apply just as they do to classes with the class-key `struct` or `class`. One obvious exception is stated in 12.6.2/8: "An attempt to initialize more than one non-static data member of a union renders the program ill-formed."