# brace-or-equal-Initializer in unions

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-bug

Related: [How to initialize a non-POD member in Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004941/how-to-initialize-a-non-pod-member-in-union/23005015)

The standard says

> At most one non-static data member of a union may have a brace-or-equal-initializer.

But

```
struct Point {
    Point() {}
    Point(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y) {}
    int x_, y_;
};

union U {
    int z;
    double w;
    Point p = Point(1,2);
};


#include <iostream>
int main () {
    U u;
    std::cout << u.p.x_ << ":" << u.p.y_ << std::endl;
}
```

prints `4196960:0` instead of the expected `1:2`.

I consider this a compiler bug. Is that so?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to compile, as the union's default constructor should be implicitly deleted due to `Point` not having a trivial default constructor. Unless, of course, that member initialization counts as a user-provided default constructor.

Comment: g++ prints 134514827:-1218232320

Comment: I forgot to mention. My g++ installation reproducebily (is that a word?) prints that.

Comment: After some searching, this seems to be a GCC bug.

Comment: @Veritas What is the bug? the result or allowing it compiles? I have the same doubt of chris. default constructor should be implicity deleted or the member initialization counts as a user-provided default constructor?

Comment: Allowing it to compile. As the constructor he is using is non-trivial this is a union-specific case where the default constructor is deleted. It should and does work for classes and structs.

Comment: I conjecture that clang is compiling this successfully because it provisionally implements a solution for [Core Working Group issue 1623](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1623) as an extension: "Because the presence of a non-static data member initializer is the moral equivalent of a mem-initializer, these rules should probably be modified not to define the generated constructor as deleted when a union member has a non-static data member initializer." Although [C++ Defect Report Support in Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) says nothing about it.

Comment: After 10 hours, all time zones should be covered. I think we don't have a consensus yet, right? Considering the latter, I am not sure if the g++-lists are the way to go. I will contact someone from the committee now :)

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: If you Point() :  x_(3), y_(4)  { } g++ is still printing out some "garbage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 [class.ctor]/5 states:

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared default constructor is an `inline public` member of its class. A defaulted default constructor for class `X` is defined as deleted if:
>
> - `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,
> - any non-static data member with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* is of reference type,
> - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* does not have a user-provided default constructor,
> - `X` is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - `X` is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - any direct or virtual base class, or non-static data member with no *brace-or-equal-initializer*, has class type `M` (or array thereof) and either `M` has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) as applied to `M`’s default constructor results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor, or
> - any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member has a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor.
>
> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is *non-trivial*.

Since the struct `Point` in the OP has a non-trivial default constructor,

```
Point() {}
```

a defaulted default constructor for a union containing a member of type `Point` *should* be defined as deleted according to the first bullet:

> - `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor

resulting in the program presented in the OP being ill-formed.

However, the committee seems to consider this to be a defect in the case that a member of a union has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, per [core working group issue 1623](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1623):

> According to 12.1 [class.ctor] paragraph 5,
>
> > A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
> >
> > - `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,
> > - ...
> > - `X` is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> > - `X` is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> > - ...
>
> Because the presence of a non-static data member initializer is the moral equivalent of a *mem-initializer*, these rules should probably be modified not to define the generated constructor as deleted when a union member has a non-static data member initializer. (Note the non-normative references in 9.5 [class.union] paragraphs 2-3 and 7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv] paragraph 2 that would also need to be updated if this restriction is changed.)
>
> It would also be helpful to add a requirement to 9.5 [class.union] requiring either a non-static data member initializer or a user-provided constructor if all the members of the union have const-qualified types.
>
> On a more general note, why is the default constructor defined as deleted just because a member has a non-trivial default constructor? The union itself doesn't know which member is the active one, and default construction won't initialize any members (assuming no *brace-or-equal-initializer*). It is up to the “owner” of the union to control the lifetime of the active member (if any), and requiring a user-provided constructor is forcing a design pattern that doesn't make sense. Along the same lines, why is the default destructor defined as deleted just because a member has a non-trivial destructor? I would agree with this restriction if it only applied when the union also has a user-provided constructor.

Issue 1623 has the status "drafting," indicating that the committee believes the issue is probably a defect - why else allow a *brace-or-equal-initializer* for a union member? - but hasn't yet devoted the time to determine the proper wording for a resolution. Indeed, the paragraph is largely the same in the current C++14 draft N3936 ([class.ctor]/4), except that the wording "any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member" is everywhere replaced by the simpler "any potentially constructed subobject."

Although the behavior of both compilers is not strictly conforming, I would consider Clang to be behaving in the spirit of the standard. It would appear that GCC becomes confused by the combination of deleted default constructor and *brace-or-equal-initializer*:

- it does [diagnose the program as ill-formed in the absence of the *brace-or-equal-initializer*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34bdcc508403bb88),
- with the *brace-or-equal-initializer* present and maximum warnings GCC 4.8.2 performs no initialization of the union at all, and [even warns that the members are used uninitialized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51ad4d2c632c18ef):

  ```
  main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
  main.cpp:17:39: warning: 'u.U::p.Point::y_' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
       std::cout << u.p.x_ << ":" << u.p.y_ << std::endl;
                                         ^
  main.cpp:17:22: warning: 'u.U::p.Point::x_' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
       std::cout << u.p.x_ << ":" << u.p.y_ << std::endl;
                        ^
  ```

GCC should probably either conform to the standard and diagnose the program as ill-formed, or emulate clang's behavior and generate a proper constructor from the *brace-or-equal-initializer*.